# Keras LSTM model on huge data

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to build a LSTM model on sequential data having 500 timestamp with 6M sequences. Due to the limitations of hardware configuration I can't convert the entire data into numpy array. In kears, is it okay if I create data in chunks and feed the model.

Below is the method I am using.

```
For epoch in range(10):
    While I<6000000:
        Data1=np.array(datax[I:I+100000])
        Data2=np.array(datay[I:I+100000])
        Model.fit(Data1, Data2, epochs=1, batch_size=100)
        I=I+100000
```

Is this method correct?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that method is quite ok.

You can also create a generator for that task and use only one fit. This may reduce some overhead in calling `fit` a lot of times.

```
def dataReader(batch_size):
    while True:             #this line is just because keras needs infinite generators
        while I<6000000:
            Data1=np.array(datax[I:I+batch_size])
            Data2=np.array(datay[I:I+batch_size])

            #you could even load the data partially here from the HD 
            #instead of loading the entire lists datax and datay
            #this will leave you more memory for having bigger models

            yield (Data1,Data2)
            I=I+batch_size
```

Then use `fit_generator`:

```
batch_size=100
steps = 6000000 // batch_size
Model.fit_generator(dataReader(batch_size), steps_per_epoch=steps,epochs=10,...)
```